# iGraph R convert edge id to vertex set

Tags: r, igraph

I have an igraph graph object (g) in R:

```
IGRAPH UN-- 50 159 -- 
attr: name (v/c), weight (e/n)
```

I need to output a list of vertex pairs for each edge - what is the quickest way to do this?

The edge sequence from E(g) is:

```
[1]   V11 -- V1  
[2]   V10 -- V2  
[3]   V13 -- V3  
[4]   V34  -- V4  
[5]   V25  -- V4 
...
```

and I am trying to output:

```
[1]   11 1
[2]   10 2
[3]   13 3
[4]   34 4
[5]   25 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get.edgelist`, e.g.:

```
> library(igraph)
> g <- erdos.renyi.game(5, 0.3)
> get.edgelist(g)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    4
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    2    5
[4,]    3    5
[5,]    4    5
```

Comment: This outputs a string list [1] "V1" "V2" etc. Will the function add.edges() recognise the string? I am trying to add these edges to another graph. Thanks

Comment: Use `get.edgelist(g, names=FALSE)`if you want the numeric ids instead of the symbolic names.